# Sum df columns for weighted average

Tags: python, pandas

Backstory: I have a pandas dataframe `scaledData` that is just a standard df of information as follows:

```
                  COL NAME0 COL NAME1  ...    COL NAME3    COL NAME4
0                Alabama     4.099099  ...    2.042345      1.392755
1                 Alaska     1.396396  ...    1.000000      1.000000
2                Arizona     4.189189  ...    2.003257      1.537777
3               Arkansas     2.927928  ...    2.208723      1.007370
4             California     3.378378  ...    1.754930      2.012395
5               Colorado     3.378378  ...    3.282196      2.843435
6            Connecticut     5.000000  ...    1.452587      4.277286
7               Delaware     4.409692  ...    2.134501      1.970434
8   District of Columbia     5.000000  ...    1.000000      1.000000
9                Florida     4.628118  ...    1.806412      2.213038
10               Georgia     4.628118  ...    1.513896      2.748559
11                Hawaii     3.902494  ...    2.891694      3.872309
12                 Idaho     1.090703  ...    2.978469      4.127419
13              Illinois     4.537415  ...    1.242970      1.888353
14               Indiana     4.537415  ...    2.368881      2.307914
15                  Iowa     2.088435  ...    3.298368      3.421122
16                Kansas     2.723356  ...    2.791375      2.160330
17              Kentucky     3.902494  ...    1.692890      4.133744
18             Louisiana     2.451247  ...    1.000000      1.000000
19                 Maine     3.448980  ...    2.535328      5.000000
20              Maryland     5.000000  ...    1.632194      1.046567
```

I want to create another column `Total` in this df that is a result of adding all of the column values per each state (COL NAME0) divided by the sum of a dictionary `weights`. Additionally, column `E` to perform the same total but only for columns with those specific tags. The `weights` dictionary's key is the column names of the df and the values are a tuple containing the weight values for the columns (used previously but irrelevant to this problem) and the category the column belongs to. Here is my current implementation:

```py
weights = {'COL NAME1': (2.14, 'E'), 'COL NAME2': (5.14, 'E'), 'COL NAME3': (10, 'G'), 'COL NAME4' : (5, 'E')}

eWeights = { key: value for key, value in weights.items() if value[1] == 'E'}
gWeights = { key: value for key, value in weights.items() if value[1] == 'G'}

#Total should be the result of adding each of the columns per COL NAME0 row 
#and dividing by the sum of the weight values. 

scaledData['Total'] = scaledData.sum(axis = 1, skipna = True)/ sum(list(weights.values())[0])

#Same calculation on only columns marked 'E'

for key in eWeights:
    scaledData['E'] = scaledData['E'] + scaledData[key]
    scaledData['E'] = scaledData['E'] / sum(list(eWeights.values())[0])
```

Unfortunately, the above code results in the following error (caused by the line creating the `Total` column in `scaledData`) :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

I've simplified the `scaledData` and `weights` but any solution or suggestions will help me with my actual df with many more rows and columns. Appreciate the help and let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your df seems to be stored as float. Try:

```
for key in eWeights:
    scaledData['E'] = scaledData['E'].astype(float) + scaledData[key].astype(float)

    scaledData['E'] / sum(list(eWeights.values())[0])
    # should this be a print? Are you trying to set any values?
```

Comment: whoops sorry i messed up the copy/paste. ill fix it right now

Comment: im receiving the error at the line above the for loop actually- ill clarify